# My class created doesn't export an object

Tags: javascript, class, object

I need to create the class ShoppingCart in the file ShoppingCart.js and export it to a test file and i get the error that my class is not a constructor

I know the problem is not in import export because before creating the js file i got the error that it couldn't find the module. I also tried creating a new instance of the class inside the file and it worked

```
file ShoppingCart.js
class ShoppingCart{
    constructor(name){
        this.name=name
    }
}

module.exports = { ShoppingCart}
```

The code for my test file is

```
 const ShoppingCart = require("./ShoppingCart")
 new ShoppingCart()
```

when i run the test file i get

```
TypeError: ShoppingCart is not a constructor
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are currently exporting an object with a *property* of `ShoppingCart`:

```
module.exports = { ShoppingCart }
//               ^^   object   ^^
```

Just export `ShoppingCart`:

```
module.exports = ShoppingCart;
```

Or, when importing, reference the `ShoppingCart` property of the object:

```
const { ShoppingCart } = require("./ShoppingCart")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're exporting an *object* with a `ShoppingCart` property.

Either:

1. Change your export to `module.exports = ShoppingCart;`, **or**
2. Change your `require` to `const { ShoppingCart } = require("./ShoppingCart");`

If you're using a modern version of Node.js, you might consider using ESM (**E**CMA**S**cript **M**odules) instead (`export`/`import`):

```
export class ShoppingCart{
    constructor(name){
        this.name=name
    }
}
```

and

```
import { ShoppingCart } from "./ShoppingCart.js";
new ShoppingCart();
```

That uses JavaScript's native modules rather than Node.js's CommonJS variant. Over the new couple of years, this will become the standard way of doing it. For now, to use ESM you use the `--experimental-modules` flag and a `package.json` containing `type: "module"`. (Or, instead of the `package.json` `type` field, you can use the file extension `.mjs`.) [Details here](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html).